# filter the objects from nested collection of Mongo db?

Tags: java, java-stream

DeviceType.java

```
private String Id;
private List<DeviceTelemetry> telemetries = new ArrayList<>()
//Getter Setter
```

DeviceTelemetry.java (Enum Class)

```
private String name;
private String description;
//Getter Setter
```

I want to fetch all *DeviceType* **Id** , which have *DeviceTelemetry* **name** start with "System"(String).

I did something like this:-

```
List<DeviceType> filteredStartWithDeviceType =deviceTypes.stream().
             filter(f -> f.getTelemetries().stream()
             .anyMatch(g -> g.getName().startsWith("System"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can Anyone tell me how can I get *DeviceType* **Id** from this?

Comment: No because I have enum class inside main class(Nested Type). I want to fetch main class data , by filtering enum one !

Comment: I don’t see how that is relevant. The filtering you have in your question seems to be working already, and the only question you put is how to get the DeviceType id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `map` the values from `DeviceType` to `String`

```java
List<String> filteredStartWithDeviceType = deviceTypes.stream()
    .filter(f -> f.getTelemetries().stream()
             .anyMatch(g -> g.getName().startsWith("System")))
    .map(DeviceType::getId) // or .map(dt -> dt.getId()) if you prefer this syntax
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yup, Thanks a lot, But one question what if I want to return all DeviceType(List) instead of just id?

Comment: @GopalSakhwala you are already returning that in the code you put in the question, right?

Comment: @GopalSakhwala you re already doing it on the snipped on your question...